# Callable: Caller is not the owner (onlyOwner protected function call fails on upgradable contract)

Tags: brownie, upgrading

I follow this https://github.com/brownie-mix/upgrades-mix repository to create transparent upgradable contract. It worked fine. Then I edited my contract and restricted some of the functions to `onlyOwner`. However once I do that, I cannot call those functions that are `onlyOwner` protected. I'm thinking that the reason for this is that only owner is the looking for the caller who is the one deploying it, in my case it is my account, but as we are calling the function via proxy contract, caller is not my account anymore and it is proxy contract. My other guess is that owner of the contract is not even set. Because if I put public function which just returns `msg.sender` it returns 0 address instead of my address. I'm new to this topics and I apologize if I couldn't express the issue elaborately. Below I will put the way I upgrade my contract and call functions from there. The TransparentProxy and ProxyAdmin contracts are exactly same as in the repo I shared above.

Upgrade:

```py
def main():
    account = get_account(network, accounts)
    proxy_admin = ProxyAdmin[-1]
    print(f"Deploying new implementation contract to {network.show_active()}")
    implementationV2 = MyTokenV2.deploy(
        {"from": account},
    )
    proxy = TransparentUpgradeableProxy[-1]

    upgrade_tx = upgrade(
        account, proxy, implementationV2, proxy_admin_contract=proxy_admin
    )
    upgrade_tx.wait(1)
    print("Proxy has been upgraded!")
```

Operations:

```py
def main():
    account = get_account(network, accounts)
    proxy_admin = ProxyAdmin[-1]
    proxy = TransparentUpgradeableProxy[-1]
    proxy_contract = Contract.from_abi("MyTokenV2", proxy.address, MyTokenV2.abi)
    txt = proxy_contract.setBalanceLimit.call(15, {"from": account})
    txt.wait(1)
    print(f"value {proxy_contract.balanceLimit()}")
```

Here `setBalanceLimit` is accepting only one argument, and it is protected by `onlyOwner` modifier

Comment: Could you add your modification of the `get_account(network, accounts)` function?

Comment: sure here it is

```py
def get_account(network, accounts):
    if network.show_active() == "development":
        return accounts[0]

    return accounts.add(os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY"))```

Comment: What about the `MyTokenV2` contract. TIP: You can edit the question and add it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Basically, I just added `onlyOwner` modifier to the contract you can see in the above repository. You can see contracts in that repository in the `contracts` directory. The box is meant to be version 1 and BoxV2 to be version 2. It is working if I do not apply `onlyOwner` modifier. When I apply it I cannot call it, I get `caller is not the owner`

Comment: Are you using the [Ownable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol) contract? i.e. `contract MyContract is Ownable`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/eSNHM2nR here is the contract and for proxyAdmin and transpareProxy contracts I use exactly same as in the repo i provided in the main question above